# How to fetch drop down value on update page

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating one IMS System. On order page I put one drop down list when I select any option from drop down it working perfectly but when it redirect to update page drop down filed data is coming blank. If anyone know solution than please help. Below is my code of `create.php`

```
<select class="form-control select_group party" data-row-id="row_1"
        id="party_1" name="name" style="width:100%;" required>
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php
      $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'stock')
               or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
      $query = "SELECT * FROM partys";
      $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>">
      <?php echo $row['name'] ?
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And for `update.php`

```
<select class="form-control select_group party" data-row-id="row_1" id="party_1" 
        name="name" style="width:100%;" required>
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php
      $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'stock')
               or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
      $query = "SELECT * FROM partys";
      $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  ?>
  <option <?php if (!empty($name) && $name == $row['name']) echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?> value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><?php echo $row['party_id'];?>
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you assign `$name`?

Comment: i have taken field name for customer field is name so i have writen $name  in update file

Comment: `name` is the index of what ever request method you are using. `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: No i am not using it